# Force Internet Explorer 10 to open in non-compatibility view

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Is there any way to force IE10 to open all sites in non-compatibility view? The only way I can do it is by pressing F12 and changing the mode but I have to do it every time I open a new tab. The list for websites to open in compatibility view is empty.

**Edit:**

The compatibility view settings are like this:

[image: 1]

- Websites added is empty
- Display all is **uncheck**
- Display intranet is **uncheck**
- Download list is **uncheck**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to disable permantly compatibility view

Go to the registry (run->regedit) look for:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

Create a **DWORD** as **iexplore.exe** and give value **10001**. (decimal value)
Restart your IE

**Note:** you can set any browse mode as default with the following values

- **11001** (0x2AF9    Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11
  edge mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
- **11000** (0x2AF8)   IE11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE
  directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode. Default value for IE11.
- **10001** (0x2711)   Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10
  Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
- **10000** (0x02710)  Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing
  standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards
  mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
- **9999** (0x270F)   Windows Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in
  IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the!DOCTYPE directive.
- **9000** (0x2328)   Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing
  standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.
  Default value for Internet Explorer 9.   Important  In Internet
  Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives
  are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
- **8888** (0x22B8)   Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode,
  regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
- **8000** (0x1F40)   Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE
  directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet
  Explorer 8   Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing
  standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards
  mode.
- **7000** (0x1B58)   Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE
  directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for
  applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.

[Source Microsoft, Internet Feature Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Go to tools - compatibility view settings and uncheck last two options:

Display intranet sites in compatibility view

and

Use Microsoft Compatibility lists

Comment: Yes all that is unchecked, and the problem still persist

Comment: Clear cache and cookies. For specific website cache clear, press ctrl+f5 .

Comment: Nope still showing the site on Compatibility view