# How to make Internet Explorer ignore X-UA-Compatible-specified legacy document modes?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

When [compatibility view](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/06/17/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults.aspx) has been disabled in all ways possible it seems that Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 honours a website’s `X-UA-Compatible` value<sup>†</sup>. This happens outside of compatibility view (the icon is missing from the address bar) and is not caused by compatibility lists or a `<!DOCTYPE>` directive.

Is there any way for the **user** (not the web developer) to choose a document mode for a website, overriding the website’s `X-UA-Compatible` value?

[Force Internet Explorer 10 to open in non-compatibility view](https://superuser.com/questions/829348/force-internet-explorer-10-to-open-in-non-compatibility-view) has accepted [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/835341) that works by defining the default document mode with regard to the `<!DOCTYPE>` directive. I've tried the registry trick without success. While it may have solved the problem for the other author’s question, my question has to do with `X-UA-Compatibile` headers.

---

<sup>†</sup> Picasa Web Albums defines `X-UA-Compatible` as `IE=EmulateIE7`. Opening the F12 developer tools and switching document mode from 7 to anything newer (8, 9, 10, Edge) instantly fixes the website. However changes done through the developer tools do not persist.

Comment: Why not open it in Firefox or Chrome? They will always render as the latest browser

Comment: @GaneshR. because average users do not want to juggle several browsers. I will always recommend they switch to a non-IE browser, but that doesn’t change my question about Internet Explorer’s document mode behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate, yes, though IE11 was not displaying the compatibility view icon in the address bar in my case. Don’t know if there is a difference between the automatic document mode switch and the website requested one.

Comment: As for the missing icon: any chance the site's URL [has been added to intranet sites](http://superuser.com/questions/215735/ie-why-does-compatibility-view-disappear-for-some-websites/215746#215746)?

Comment: @Arjan, it hasn’t, it was the first thing I checked when Picasa acted up. The list is empty and none of those checkboxes make a difference to the outcome.

Comment: I have updated the question to (hopefully) explain why this issue is different from most compatibility mode related questions. Also hope this differentiates my question from the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a persistent Document mode to a site in the user's Internet Explorer by [using Enterprise mode site list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872481.aspx) (Look at the `Adding your site to the Enterprise Mode site list` section). This is turned off by default, so you need to [enable it using Group Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640699.aspx). Note that this is only available for Windows 8.1, Internet Explorer 11 users.

Comment: This may be a workaround though not the solution to my specific question as it doesn’t specify a document mode _locally_, it requires a server to distribute a list. Group Policy also isn’t available to me as it does not come with every sub-version of Windows 8.1.

Comment: You can use a local XML file instead of a server file for the website list, so it doesn't really require a server to distribute a list (though I've not personally tried this so cannot verify). But yes, it is only available in Windows 8.1 pro version.

Comment: I got the impression from the Microsoft documentation that the enterprise list required the XML file to be served over HTTP. Maybe I misread it.

Comment: In the 2nd link, they give 3 examples of XML files (in the last few lines of the page), `HTTP location`, `Local network` and `Local file`.

Comment: I totally missed that, sorry @Chirag64! I will see if this can somehow be activated on non-Pro versions of Windows 8.1 and if it would be able to override `X-UA-Compatible` values.

Comment: You could try a 3rd party utility Group Policy Editor - http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/ (not tried it myself though, so can't guarantee this will work)